# Container slideshow control to display on all but last item

Tags: php, containers, slideshow

I have the following php,

```
<?php
  $items_position = $helper->get('position');
  $mods = JModuleHelper::getModules($items_position);
  $count = count($mods); 

  $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
  $doc->addScript (T3_TEMPLATE_URL . '/acm/container-slideshow/js/landing/jquery.easing.js');
  $doc->addScript (T3_TEMPLATE_URL.'/acm/container-slideshow/js/landing/jquery.mousewheel.min.js');
  $doc->addScript (T3_TEMPLATE_URL.'/acm/container-slideshow/js/landing/jquery.singular.js');
?>

<div class="style-1 block-landing">
  <?php $i = 1; foreach ($mods as $mod) : ?>
  <div class="block-landing-item <?php if (isset($animation)) echo $animation; ?>" id="block-landing-item-<?php echo $mod->id; ?>">
    <?php
      echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($mod);
  ?>

  <?php if (($i==$count-1) && $helper->get('enable-leave-slide')): ?>
    <a class="arrow-bottom block-landing-next" href="#"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-down"></i></a>
  <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
  <?php $i++; endforeach; ?>



  <div class="mod-nav">
      <ul class="block-landing-nav">
          <?php $i = 0; foreach ($mods as $mod) : ?>
          <li class="mod-nav-item"><a href="#block-landing-item-<?php echo $mod->id; ?>"><?php echo $mod->id; ?></a></li>
          <?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
          <?php if($helper->get('enable-leave-slide')): ?>

          <?php endif; ?>
      </ul>
      <!-- /mod-nav -->
  </div>
</div>

<script>
    (function($){
        var iOS = parseFloat(('' + (/CPU.*OS ([0-9_]{1,5})|(CPU like).*AppleWebKit.*Mobile/i.exec(navigator.userAgent) || [0,''])[1]).replace('undefined', '3_2').replace('_', '.').replace('_', '')) || false;
        if(!(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) || iOS)) {
            var slide = $('.block-landing');
              var parent = slide.parents('#t3-section');
              slide.singular({
                  section: '.block-landing-item',
                  nav: '.block-landing-nav',
                  prev: '.block-landing-prev',
                  next: '.block-landing-next',
                  navActiveClass: 'block-landing-active',
                  scrollSpeed: 600,
                  mousewheel: true,
                  easing: 'easeInOutQuart',
                  scrollEnd: function(elem) {
                      if ($('.block-landing-nav .block-landing-active').hasClass('sec-last')) {
                          $('#sec-last').animate({
                              height: 0,
                              opacity: 0
                          }, 400, function() {
                              parent.addClass('slide-hide');
                              $('html, body').css('overflow', 'unset');
                          });
                      }
                  }
              });

              $(window).on('mousewheel', function(e, delta) {
                  if(delta < -0.8) {

                  }
                  if(delta > 0.8) {
                      if ($(this).scrollTop() == 0) {
                          parent.removeClass('slide-hide');
                          $('.block-landing-prev', '#sec-last').click();
                          $('html, body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
                      }
                  }
              });
        } else {
            $('.home-landing').css('overflow','unset');
            $('.block-landing').css('position','static');
            $('.block-landing > div').css('height','auto!important');
            $('.block-landing-nav').css('display','none');
        }
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

This code is used to generate a little arrow that points down to let you know that you need to scroll in my container slideshow.

The problem is that the little arrow only shows on the last slide item. It should show on all of the slides except from the last slide.

Don't suppose anyone could help me to display this on all but last?

Thanks,
Richard

Comment: You should post the whole for loop so other can get a better idea what problem are you facing?

Comment: @Suraj I posted the full php below :)